# How do I convert a column of dates in integer format to date format in base R?

Tags: r, date

I'm working with a dataframe that has a column of dates, all of which are integers in the form `20210117` for January 17, 2021.

I tried to run
`data$DATE <- as.Date(as.character(data$DATE), "%Y%m%d")`

but this turns all my dates into NAs. What am I doing wrong and is there a way to fix this in base R without importing libraries?

Comment: I can't reproduce your question and it is [working for me](https://rextester.com/KUS13169).

Comment: `as.Date("20210117", "%Y%m%d")` works fine. What exactly do you have? How is the answer below different than what you already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `format` option when calling `as.Date`:

```
dates <- as.character(data$YearMonthDay)
data$newVar = as.Date(dates, format="%Y%m%d")
```

Note that you don't need to use the `origin` parameter here, because even though you are passing in numerical data, it is in the form of an actual text date. `origin` is used when passing in number of days since an epoch.

It is generally not advisable to go in this direction, and in any case, base R date's have to have a year component. So, include the year component, and if you don't want to use it, then don't use it.